# How to install ism malayalam in ubuntu

Tags: fonts, language-support, malayalam

Can I install ism malayalam typing software in ubuntu ?.Some one told me that riming tone is the alternative,but it also have some irregularity with ism malayalam.

Comment: Yes, you may. But the software is not a Ubuntu package.

Comment: Thank you, Will you please tell me How can I do this ?

Comment: 1. Ask software maker. 2. Use Windows OS. 3. You can install `wine` on Ubuntu, but it does not guarantee the software working on it at all.